# Learning Java 8 - For Map Entry

Tags: java, java-8

Is there is a simpler way to achieve the following code using Java 8?

```
    Enumeration headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
    List<Entry<String, String>> headers = new ArrayList<>();
    while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
        String headerName = (String) headerNames.nextElement();
        headers
            .add(Map.entry(headerName, request.getHeader(headerName)));
    }
```

### EDIT:

Yes the request is HttpServletRequest

Comment: What is `request`? My guess would be that it got a method to return a map of headers. Btw. why are you using a `List` of `Map.Entry` instead of an actual `Map`?

Comment: Hi, one small improvement to this would be removing the cast, as Java EE's `getHeaderNames()` method returns a generic type `Enumeration<String>` for you. :)

Comment: @Amongalen pretty sure this is [HttpServletRequest](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) - I'll let OP confirm

Comment: You tagged your question with `[java-8]`, but use the method `Map.entry` of Java 9.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do like this

```
Collections.list(request.getHeaderNames()).stream()
            .map(e->new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(e,request.getHeader(e)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: There is a missing `<>` in the initialization of `SimpleEntry` within the map operation. Why use a `toString` in one place and not in the other?

Answer (score 2):

A simple answer which does not involve creating `Entry` objects manually:

```java
Collections.list(request.getHeaderNames())
    .stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.toMap(
            Function.identity(), 
            header -> Collections.list(httpRequest.getHeaders(header))
    ));
```

See alternate approach in [Hadi J's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59244770/8027026).

Answer (score 0):

Since `public Enumeration<String> getHeaderNames();` is still part of even **Java EE 8 API**, I would stick with it. You could remove some of your casting using `Enumeration<String>` instead of the typeless variant.

All Java 8 variants I saw using `Stream API` have the "disadvantage" of first creating a list out of your Enumeration. Look at the SourceCode of `Collection.list`. It builds a new `ArrayList`.

In addition, you can ask, if the already published (and correct) answers could be considered to be **simpler**. But as always I think this is a matter of taste.